# Change value of type Bool by using string

Tags: swift, function

I am making a little game, by improving my Swift language, so I am not familiar with all the functions of Swift. That's why I am asking this:

I have:

```
var Playedcardone: Bool = false
var Playedcardtwo: Bool= false
ect ect ect
```

my IBAction, this is hooked up with 52 cards:

```
@IBAction func Tappedoncard(card: UIButton) {
        if tapped == true{ //nvm this
        checkcard(card)
    }
    }
```

In a function, I have:

```
func checkcard(Card: UIButton) {
        ("Playedcard" + Card.currentTitle!) = true
    }
```

Well as you may guess this function doesn't work. How can I reference to a var I made depending on the card that I called? When the card is ticked, the bool needs to change to true. I can do this by creating 52 vars, and 51 else if statements, but there should be a quicker option right? You help is welcome :).

/offtopic: I know I could used classes, to define my card value, UIIMageview and the bool itself. I just don't understand classes optimal, maybe for my next app I will use. If you want to see my code, and you want to give me a hand, just ask and I will drop the code here.

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to do? do you want the function to change the var to true?

Comment: @Jhonnyjammer please post more code and clarify your goal. So that others and I can help you.

Comment: I updated my post. Please have another look.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable using a string as you are trying to do. You will need to preform some type of conditional checking to update the variables like so.

```
func checkcard(Card: UIButton) {
    if Card.currentTitle! == "one" {
      Playedcardone = true
    } else if Card.currentTitle! == "two" {
      Playedcardtwo = true
    }
}
```

There is a plethora of different solutions you could use - for example why not make two seperate IBActions for each card? Also as a matter of convention I would suggest using lowercase letters to start your variables.

Comment: This way, I need to add 52 variables, and 51 else if statements, to determine what the card's current title is... Isn't there another option? You say I could create 2 separate IBActions, but what should contain the other IBAction?

Comment: @Jhonnyjammer if that's the case you will need a different approach to storing your cards consider using an array